All stationary martingales are constant?
Suppose $(X_{n})_{n\geq{1}}$ is a stationary process that is a martingale with respect to some filtration. Suppose also that $\mathbb{E}X_{0}^{2}<\infty$ so that $\mathbb{E}X_{n}^{2}<\infty$ for all $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$, by stationarity. Then it is a straightforward exercise to show that $X_{n}=X_{0}$ a.s. for all $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$.
Is this still true if you remove the second moment assumption? Namely, is it true that $X_{n}=X_{0}$ a.s. for all $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$ if $(X_{n})_{n\geq{1}}$ is a stationary martingale? If so, how do you prove this?

Almost the same argument seems to work: By Jensen's inequality, $\mathbb E (\sqrt{1+X_n^2} \vert \mathscr F_0) \geqslant \sqrt{1 + X_0^2}$, and the inequality is strict with positive probability unless $X_n = X_0$ almost surely. Thus, $\mathbb E \sqrt{1+X_n^2} \geqslant \mathbb E \sqrt{1 + X_0^2}$, and the inequality is strict unless $X_n = X_0$ almost surely. If $(X_n)$ is stationary, we necessarily have $\mathbb E \sqrt{1+X_n^2} = \mathbb E \sqrt{1 + X_0^2}$, and therefore $X_n = X_0$ almost surely. Does this make sense?

Very slick solution!

And this argument doesn't use the full stationarity, only that $X^2_n$ has the same distribution as $X^2_0$, for all $n$.

Yes! Any stationary process $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ with $X_0\in L_1$ is bounded in $L_1$. Any $L_1$-bounded martingale converges with probability $1$. Any stationary process which converges with probability $1$ has $X_n=X_0$ for all $n$ with probability $1$.
There are nice almost-counterexamples. You can take a Markov chain which has the martingale property when started from any given initial state, and which is positive recurrent so has a stationary version. For example, take state-space $\{0,\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 8, \dots\}$; let $p_{0,1}=p_{0,-1}=1/2$, and for $k\ne 0$ let $p_{k,0}=p_{k,2k}=1/2$. But the stationary distribution is not integrable so the stationary process fails to be a martingale.

How does one see the last claim in the first paragraph? Is there a simple proof, or is it complicated?

If $X_n$ converges a.s. as $n\to\infty$ then $X_{n+1}-X_n\to 0$ a.s. So also $X_{n+1}-X_n\to 0$ in distribution as $n\to\infty$. So by stationarity also $X_1-X_0\to 0$ in distribution as $n\to\infty$. But then $X_1-X_0$ must be $0$ with probability $1$.

Ah, very cool! @James Martin

I think this is true, at least for martingales with almost surely bounded increments, i.e. $X_t - X_{t-1} \in L^{\infty}$ for all $t$. I was unable to prove the general case though.
We first need the following
Lemma: For identically distributed, positive $L^1$ random variables $Y, Z$, we have $$\mathbb E \left[ \frac{Y}{Z} \right] \geq 1$$
with $\mathbb E\left [ \frac{Y}{Z} \right ] = 1$ exactly when $Y = Z$ almost surely.
Proof (sketch): The first claim is straightforward by Jensen’s inequality applied to $\log \left (\frac{Y}{Z} \right)$. For the characterisation of equality, the idea is that to achieve a minimum value for the expectation, you want the denominator to be as large as possible whenever the numerator is; and this together with the fact that the numerator and denominator are identically distributed implies the conclusion. $\square$
Now we prove the main theorem. It will suffice to prove it for just one step, i.e. we need only show that $X_0 = X_1$ almost surely, and the general case follows inductively.
Set $B := 1 + |X_0| + \|X_1 - X_0\|_{L^\infty}$.
We note that $X_0 + B$ and $X_1 + B$ are almost surely positive. Further, $B$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X_0)$.
Since $X$ is a martingale, we have $\mathbb E \left [ \frac{X_1 + B}{X_0 + B}\right ] = \mathbb E \left [ \mathbb E \left [ \frac{X_1 + B}{ X_0 + B} \big | X_0 \right ] \right ] = 1$. Applying the Lemma we have $X_1 + B = X_0 + B$ a.s., so $X_1 = X_0$ a.s. and so we are done.

This is not true if you remove the second moment hypothesis.  A counterexample is $dX_t = \sqrt{1 + X_t^2} \, dW_t.$ You see that it satisfies the usual lipshitz condition and is a martingale, and by inspection it has a Cauchy distribution as it’s stationary distribution.  An attempt to do the same with a distribution with a first moment would run afoul of feller’s test for explosions , consistent with the positive answers assuming an $L^1$ condition

a Martingale cannot have a Cauchy Law- did you mean a local Martingale?
